# LVM SSD cachepool how to trim (Debian 10)

Tags: debian, lvm, cache, fstrim

I was playing with LVM and I was setting up a volume with ext4 on an HDD and I want to use an SSD as a cache.

What I first done was
`lvcreate --type cache-pool -l 100%FREE -n datacache SSD /dev/sda3
lvcreate --type cache -l 100%FREE -n data --cachepool datacache SSD --cachemode writeback /dev/sdb1`
So respectivily I created a cache-pool voume called datacache and than a vomume called data attached to datacache.

I think (the problem is I don't remember) that fstrim works perfectly in this way.

Then I had to do some operations on disk and I had to deattach my cache. So I uncached my disk

`lvconvert --uncache /dev/mapper/SSD-data`

Then I moved the disk (and other thinks) and at the end I reattached my disk to a cache-pool

`lvcreate --type cache-pool -l 100%FREE -n datacache SSD /dev/sda3
lvconvert --type cache --cachemode writeback --cachepool datacache SSD/data`

The problem is that now if I fstrim i obtain
`root@me:~# fstrim -a
fstrim: /mnt/data: FITRIM ioctl failed: Argument not valid`
I am not completly sure that before detaching and reattaching the cache it worked, but I suppose to because I tested fstrim and I don't remember any errors.

I am using debian buster.
`root@me:~# uname -a
Linux me 4.19.0-14-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.171-2 (2021-01-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Thank you in advice. If I missed some important information I am really sorry. Tell me what you need and I'll post it  :D